# Full CRUD Functionality with Filepond in Vue 3, Inertia and Laravel 10 Backend (uploading images)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, upload, inertiajs, filepond

I've been searching extensively for a comprehensive example or guide that demonstrates full CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functionality using Filepond with Vue, and Inertia JS integrated with a Laravel backend, but I haven't found a single resource that **covers all the details I need**. I'm reaching out here in the hope of getting some guidance or resources.

Here's what I'm specifically looking to implement in my Vue application with Laravel as the backend:

1. **Uploading Multiple Files:** Allow users to upload multiple files using Filepond.
2. **Pre-Upload Deletion:** Enable users to delete selected files before they are uploaded or submitted.
3. **Re-Ordering Images:** Feature to reorder the images in the Filepond interface.
4. **Loading Existing Images:** Load existing images in the Filepond form, useful for editing entries.
5. **Associating Images with a Product ID:** Store images in relation to a specific product ID in my Laravel backend.
6. **Auto-Deletion of Temporary Upload Folder:** Automatically delete the temporary images upload folder after a certain period.

I've searched throughout the entire internet, literally. This is the first time I've been so desperate to ask a question here. Any guidance, resources, or examples specific to Vue with a Laravel backend, using Filepond for file management, would be immensely appreciated!

While trying, I've installed:

- Vue Filepond: https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond (with FilePondPluginFileValidateType and FilePondPluginImagePreview)
- Laravel Filepond Backend: https://github.com/rahulhaque/laravel-filepond
- Checked out all documention.
- Checked out all video's (even in f* French).
- Tried to GPT it.
- Can't seem to find out how Filepond is really working.

Comment: The question is too broad for SO, asking for resources is offtopic, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I had the same problem and did exactly what you did. I watched all the tutorials and then I did it, but uploading files to the server, then uploading files to the edit form, then adding new files to already existing files and deleting already existing files with a modal window with reordering and saving this order in database took me literally... a month of work + help from the author of the plugin, which I really appreciated I thank him from here. Thank you Rik.

Comment: But this is not simple solution... the biggest problem I encountered was uploading files to filepond and the problem with cors policy, as well as launching a modal window asking whether you are sure to delete the file before its final deletion from the server. Since chatGPT doesn't know how to do it... it means that my intelligence is winning for now.

Comment: I don't have much time right now to make a tutorial that would show how to solve this problem. This seemingly simple topic is very complex. So far, I have left console.log in the code to know if everything is working correctly, and I inserted it practically after every action. I also can't share my app code because I'm under contract.

Comment: I'll give you a hint. Watch carefully the tutorials from the Internet and bring the application to the point where in the form for adding a new item you can add files that are temporarily uploaded to the server, and after clicking save, they are transferred from the temporary directory to the directory appropriate for a given item, how you will do it and show me on github what you did, I will help you further.